# how can i resolve invalid identifier error

Tags: sql, oracle

I have run below query

```
 v_sql2 := 'SELECT SUBSTR((SUM(CASE
                           WHEN srm_bill_date between "01-04-2022" and "01-04-2023" THEN
                            (SUM(srm_bill_amount) / 10000000)
                            END)),
                            0,
                            4) AS FY_Revenue_InCr
              FROM m_servicemaster
             GROUP BY srm_bill_date';
```

result gives error :

> ```
> ORA-00904: "01-04-2023": invalid identifier
> ```

I need solution for this

Comment: please help me to resolve above issue

Comment: Convert to `date'2023-01-04'` in order to express January the fourth, or to `date'2023-04-01'` in order to express April the first.

Comment: Please provide sample data and your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Double quotes are for identifiers (i.e. column or table names, etc). Single quotes are for literals. You are using double quotes when you should use single quotes (and you are using strings for dates when you should use date literals).

Since you are using single-quotes inside a string literal then you need to use two single quotes to escape them.

```sql
v_sql2 := 'SELECT SUBSTR(
                    SUM(
                      CASE
                      WHEN srm_bill_date between DATE ''2022-04-01''
                                             and DATE ''2023-04-01''
                      THEN SUM(srm_bill_amount) / 10000000
                      END
                    ),
                    0,
                    4
                  ) AS FY_Revenue_InCr
           FROM   m_servicemaster
           GROUP BY srm_bill_date';
```

or:

```sql
v_sql2 := 'SELECT SUBSTR(
                    SUM(
                      CASE
                      WHEN srm_bill_date between TO_DATE( ''01-04-2022'', ''DD-MM-YYYY'')
                                             and TO_DATE( ''01-04-2023'', ''DD-MM-YYYY'')
                      THEN SUM(srm_bill_amount) / 10000000
                      END
                    ),
                    0,
                    4
                  ) AS FY_Revenue_InCr
           FROM   m_servicemaster
           GROUP BY srm_bill_date';
```

It is also odd that you are using `SUM` twice; it is not invalid but it may not be what you want as it makes the `GROUP BY` clause seemingly irrelevant.

I would have written the query as:

```sql
v_sql2 := 'SELECT SUBSTR(SUM(srm_bill_amount / 10000000), 0, 4) AS FY_Revenue_InCr
           FROM   m_servicemaster
           WHERE  srm_bill_date >= DATE ''2022-04-01''
           AND    srm_bill_date <  DATE ''2023-04-01'';
```